# C++ using istream_iterator to copy and ostream_iterator to output

Tags: c++, iostream, istream-iterator

I tried to use the following code to input strings, find a range, and copy to output

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
 {

  vector<string> vec;
  copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(),back_inserter(vec));
  vector<string>::iterator first = find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),"start");
  vector<string>::iterator last = find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),"end");

  if(first < last)
    copy(first,last,ostream_iterator<string>(cout,"\n"));

  return 0;
 }
```

I ran the program from unix command line, and terminated input using (ctrl+z), but nothing was written to the terminal. I read other threads on istream_iterator, and I think ctrl+z is the only way to tell the program that I'm done with inputting. But it should output afterwards? (by the way, I did input strings including "start" and "end" to make sure first and last iterators are valid).

I also ran the above program from an IDE (Xcode), but it doesn't show any command line for input, is there any to show it? or do I have to do some

```
cout << "Please enter words: "
```

kind of prompt to take input?

thanks!

Comment: Ctrl-Z rarely works as EOF in Unix terminals. Try Ctrl-D.

Comment: that works now! what about running it from some IDE? like xcode? thanks!